# Terminal no muestra la ejecución de código Python

Tags: python, python-3.7

Buen día, antes que nada muchas gracias a la comunidad por dedicarle tiempo a esta consulta! Creo que es algo muy básico pero no logro el resultado esperado...

Estoy teniendo inconveniente para visualizar mi programa desde la terminal, cuando lo ejecuto me muestra los print del primer nivel, pero enseguida se vuelve a la terminal a la espera de algún comando.

El programa sigue funcionando en segundo plano ya que controla el estado de algunas IP he informa si pasa algo vía mail, y pude verificar que sigue funcionando.

Esta corriendo en una Raspberry PI4, con SO Raspberry Pi Os (Debian), Python 3.7.3

No se si hace falta copiar el código ya que es muy sencillo, pero creo que el inconveniente esta en la terminal o en el como puedo ver el programa que esta corriendo. Les pido disculpas si es un tema que no esta en el alcance de esta comunidad pero capas alguno paso por lo mismo.

A continuación mi script:

```
#! /usr//bin/env python3  
import subprocess  
import os  
import platform  
from time import sleep  
import time  
from datetime import datetime  
import datetime as dt  
from threading import Thread  
import firebase_admin  
#from firebase_admin import credentials
#from firebase_admin import db
#from firebase_admin import firestore
import re  
from funciones import enviarmailsAlarma2, hoy  
#PAHT_CRED = '/home/pi/Desktop/controlIP/cred.json'
#URL_DB = 'https://xxx.firebaseio.com/'
REF_HOME = 'xx'

prueba = ""
to = "matlaudadio@gmail.com"

                   
maxTiempoRespuesta = 120
velocidadInternetTest = 40
velocidadInternetTiempo = 90
class IOT():  
    
    #def __init__(self):  
            #try:
                # cred = credentials.Certificate(PAHT_CRED)
                 #firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
                 #'databaseURL': URL_DB})
                 #self.refHome = db.reference(REF_HOME)
                 #self.refTem = self.refHome.child('controlIP')
                     
           # except Exception as e:
                #print ("Error de credenciales")
               # print (e)
                #pass#
            
    def IControl(self):  
        #TEST VELOCIDAD INTERNET - pip install speedtest-cli
        global velocidadInternetTest
        respuestaTime = 0
        respuestaTime2 = 0
        while True:
            resultT1, resultT2 = subprocess.getstatusoutput("speedtest-cli --simple --share")
            posicionResTest = resultT2.find("Download:")
            respuestaTime = [float(s) for s in re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', resultT2[posicionResTest+10:posicionResTest+19])][0]
            fechaA = datetime.now()
            fechaT1 = str(fechaA).split(".")[0]            
            print(str(respuestaTime))
            print("Resultado " + str(resultT2))
            if respuestaTime < velocidadInternetTest:
                global to, velocidadInternetTiempo
                time.sleep(velocidadInternetTiempo)
                resultT3, resultT4 = subprocess.getstatusoutput("speedtest-cli --simple")
                posicionResTest2 = resultT4.find("Download:")
                respuestaTime2 = [float(s) for s in re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', resultT4[posicionResTest2+10:posicionResTest2+19])][0]
                #print("Test 2 "+ str(respuestaTime2))
                if respuestaTime2 < velocidadInternetTest:
                    print(resultT4)
                    asunto = "ALARMA - TEST DE VELOCIDAD DE INTERNET BAJO"
                    ipLogT = str(respuestaTime2) + "Mb < " + str(velocidadInternetTest) + "Mb"
                    enviarmailsAlarma2(self,asunto,"Internet" , fechaT1, ipLogT, "Internet","","","","ss","¡Alarma!",to)
                    print("ALARMA ENVIADA POR MAIL")
                        
            time.sleep(300)
    
    
                
    def controlIP(self):
        
            parametro = "ping -n -w 2 -n" if platform.system().lower() == "windows" else "ping -c1 -w 2 -c1"
            while True:
                with open("/home/pi/Desktop/IPControl/IPList.txt") as file:
                    dump = file.read()
                    dump = dump.splitlines()
            
                with open(os.devnull, "wb") as limbo:
                
                    ipNovedad = ""
                    ipAlarmada = ""
                    ipNombre = ""
                    ipFecha = ""
                    ipLog = ""
                    ipNovedadMax = ""
                    ipAlarmadaMax = ""
                    ipNombreMax = ""
                    ipFechaMax = ""
                    ipLogMax = ""
                    alarma = False
                    alarmaMax = False
                    for n in dump:
                        ip = n
                        
                        result, result2 = subprocess.getstatusoutput(parametro +" " + ip.split(",")[0])
                        posicion = result2.find("time")
                        
                        if result:
                                fecha = datetime.now()
                                fecha2 = str(fecha).split(".")[0]
                                tiempoRespuesta = [float(s) for s in re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', result2[posicion+5:posicion+10])][0]
                        
                                print (ip, "inactiva " + str(tiempoRespuesta) + " ms")
                                alarma = True
                                ipNovedad= ipNovedad + "¡Alarma!"+"<br><hr>"
                                ipAlarmada = ipAlarmada + ip.split(",")[0] + "<br><hr>"
                                ipNombre = ipNombre + ip.split(",")[1] + "<br><hr>"
                                ipFecha = ipFecha + fecha2 + "<br><hr>"
                                posicion2 = result2[result2.find("%")-3:result2.find("%")+13]
                                ipLog = ipLog + posicion2+ "<br><hr>"
                        else:
                            tiempoRespuesta = [float(s) for s in re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', result2[posicion+5:posicion+10])][0]
                            print (ip, "activa " + str(tiempoRespuesta) + " ms")
                            maxTiempoRespuesta = float(ip.split(",")[2])
                            if float(tiempoRespuesta) >= maxTiempoRespuesta:
                                #ESPERO 10 SEGUNDOS Y VUELVO A VERIFICAR
                                time.sleep(10)
                                result10s, result210s = subprocess.getstatusoutput(parametro +" " + ip.split(",")[0])
                                tiempoRespuesta10s = [float(s) for s in re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', result210s[posicion+5:posicion+10])][0]
                                if float(tiempoRespuesta10s) >= maxTiempoRespuesta:
                                    alarmaMax = True
                                    fecha = datetime.now()
                                    fecha2 = str(fecha).split(".")[0]
                                    ipNovedadMax = ipNovedadMax + "¡Alarma!"+"<br><hr>"
                                    ipAlarmadaMax = ipAlarmadaMax + ip.split(",")[0] + "<br><hr>"
                                    ipNombreMax = ipNombreMax + ip.split(",")[1] + "<br><hr>"
                                    ipFechaMax = ipFechaMax + fecha2 + "<br><hr>"
                                    ipLogMax = ipLogMax + str(tiempoRespuesta)+ "ms > " + str(maxTiempoRespuesta) + "ms Max"+  "<br><hr>"
                             
                                 
                    if alarmaMax:
                        asunto ="ALARMA - TIEMPO DE RESPUESTA EXCEDE LIMITE MAXIMO"
                        print(asunto)
                        global to
                        enviarmailsAlarma2(self,asunto,ipAlarmadaMax , ipFechaMax, ipLogMax, ipNombreMax,"","","","ss",ipNovedadMax,to)
                        print("ALARMA ENVIADA POR MAIL")
                        alarmaMax = False

                    if alarma:
                        ipNovedad = ipNovedad + "<br><hr>"
                        ipAlarmada = ipAlarmada + "<br><hr>"
                        ipNombre = ipNombre + "<br><hr>"
                        ipFecha = ipFecha + "<br><hr>"
                        ipLog = ipLog + "<br><hr>"
                        respuestaSuma = 0
                        #REPASO LAS IP QUE RESPONDEN PARA INFORMAR
                        for n in dump:
                            ip = n
                            result, result2 = subprocess.getstatusoutput(parametro +" " + ip.split(",")[0])
                            posicion = result2.find("time")
                            respuesta = 0
                                                  
                            if not result:
                                fecha = datetime.now()
                                fecha2 = str(fecha).split(".")[0]
                                ipNovedad= ipNovedad +"Ok!<br><hr>"
                                ipAlarmada = ipAlarmada + ip.split(",")[0] + "<br><hr>"
                                ipNombre = ipNombre + ip.split(",")[1] + "<br><hr>"
                                ipFecha = ipFecha + fecha2 + "<br><hr>"
                                
                                respuesta = [float(s) for s in re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', result2[posicion+5:posicion+10])][0]
                                ipLog = ipLog + str(respuesta )+ " ms" + "<br><hr>"
                                respuestaSuma = sum([respuestaSuma , respuesta])
                                print (ip, "activa " + result2 + "ms")
                                
                        asunto = "ALARMA - NO RESPONDE IP"
                        
                        to = "matlaudadio@gmail.com"
                        self.enviarmailsAlarma2(asunto,ipAlarmada , ipFecha, ipLog, ipNombre,"","","","ss",ipNovedad,to)
                        alarma = False
                        print("MAIL ENVIADO")
                    
                                                          
                time.sleep(60)       
                        

print ('START !')
iot = IOT()


subproceso_tem = Thread(target=iot.controlIP)
subproceso_tem.daemon = True
subproceso_tem.start()


subproceso_tem2 = Thread(target=iot.IControl)
subproceso_tem2.daemon = True
subproceso_tem2.start()
```

Comment: ¿Cómo lanzas el programa? ¿Quizás has puesto un `&` al final del comando? Si no, creo que deberías mostrar el código para ver si éste está a su vez lanzando otros procesos

Comment: Adivinos no somos. Con esa información, pura especulación.

Comment: Gracias por responder! ahí actualice y como pude...agregue el código, algo que me di cuenta es que el codigo funciona bien desde Thonny pero cuando se ejecuta por terminal imprime los dos ultimos print del codigo pero vuelve al path y no funciona. Yo pense que corria en segundo plano pero no es asi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que has marcado tus hilos como de tipo "daemon", en estas líneas:

```
subproceso_tem.daemon = True
...
subproceso_tem2.daemon = True
```

Así que en tu programa tienes tres hilos: esos dos que has creado, que son de tipo daemon, más el hilo principal que arranca todo, que no es de tipo daemon. Ese hilo principal finaliza una vez el programa principal ha terminado, por lo que quedarían en ejecución tan solo los otros dos hilos. Pero al estar marcados como tipo daemon, el proceso entero finalizará cuando queden solo esos dos hilos.

Ese es **precisamente** el significado de marcar un hilo como *daemon*. Python terminará la ejecución del proceso principal cuando todos los hilos en ejecución sean tipo *daemon*. Dicho de otra forma, cuando todos los hilos no-daemon hayan terminado. En tu caso, cuando termine el programa principal.

Hay dos posibles soluciones a esto:

1. No marcar los otros dos hilos como *daemon* ¿por qué los habías marcado así?
2. Hacer que el programa principal no termine, añadiendo por ejemplo `subproceso_tem.join()`, que hará que se quede esperando a que ese subproceso termine. Puedes añadir después también `subproceso_tem2.join()` para mayor seguridad, aunque en tu caso, ya que el hilo `subproceso_tem` no termina realmente nunca, el programa principal se quedará por siempre esperando en ese `.join()`, por lo que no terminará tampoco.

En cuanto a por qué funcionaba desde Thonny, aventuro que puede deberse a que ese IDE lanza tu programa en otro hilo más, que no termina (es el hilo de ejecución del IDE), por lo que los hilos daemon pueden permanecer en ejecución.

Comment: Muchas gracias, todo muy claro, eso funciono para mi, el motivo del uso  es por copiar parte del codigo.....y desconocer el funcionamiento de esa linea....disculpas.